# Exception creating a trading bot

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, exception, trading

I'm trying to create WordPress plugin which trades cryptocoins for my website in PHP, and I'm trying to use Bittrex API for this purpose.

My problem is that when I try to call the methods from the Class with the API, an exception is thrown.
Could someone help me to find the problem in my code?

Here is the code inside the main class, where I'm creating an Object from `Client` class.

```
require 'bittrex-master/src/edsonmedina/bittrex/Client.php';
use edsonmedina\bittrex\Client;

$keya = "xxx";
$secreta = "xxx";

$b = new Client ($keya, $secreta);

try{
    $list = $b->getMarkets ();
    echo "$list";

}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

echo "\n\n";
```

Here is the portion of code from the Client class

```
namespace edsonmedina\bittrex;

class Client
{
private $baseUrl;
private $apiVersion = 'v1.1';
private $apiKey;
private $apiSecret;

public function __construct ($apiKey, $apiSecret)
{
    $this->apiKey    = $apiKey;
    $this->apiSecret = $apiSecret;
    $this->baseUrl   = 'https://bittrex.com/api/'.$this->apiVersion.'/';
}

/**
 * Invoke API
 * @param string $method API method to call
 * @param array $params parameters
 * @param bool $apiKey  use apikey or not
 * @return object
 */
private function call ($method, $params = array(), $apiKey = false)
{
    $uri  = $this->baseUrl.$method;

    if ($apiKey == true) {
        $params['apikey'] = $this->apiKey;
        $params['nonce']  = time();
    }

    if (!empty($params)) {
        $uri .= '?'.http_build_query($params);
    }

    $sign = hash_hmac ('sha512', $uri, $this->apiSecret);

    $ch = curl_init ($uri);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign: '.$sign));
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $answer = json_decode($result);

    if ($answer->success == false) {
        throw new \Exception ($answer->message);
    }

    return $answer->result;
}

/**
 * Get the open and available trading markets at Bittrex along with other meta data.
 * @return array
 */
public function getMarkets ()
{
    return $this->call ('public/getmarkets');
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: There isn't a specific exception. The only output is "Caught exception:"  which is the output in case an excpetion is thrown

Comment: Debug! Go caveman and add print statements to find where the exception is.

Comment: I receive the exception APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment and exception `APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED`, by default your APIKEY is false in your `call` method.

```
return $this->call ('public/getmarkets', null, true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help it solved my problem